# Modal UI not working

Tags: c#, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have this implementation for bootstrap modal with jquery. However, there are parts not showing when i do inspect element. Here is the code.

```
<div class="col-md-9 filter-header">
    <a href='@Url.Action("CreateRole", "Admin")' class="btn btn-warning pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal" data-wrap="modal-lg"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fws"></i> Add Role</a>
</div>
```

Below, I have these to where the data to be put in.

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="C2T Modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
             <!--Content Inside Here--> 
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

I have jquery implementation to add the data.

```
$('.Roles')
     .on('click', 'a[data-toggle="modal"]', function () { // show modal
            $('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
      })
     .on('submit', '.ajaxForm', ajaxFormSubmit);
```

Here is the code to be put in the modal-content after calling the controller

```
@model C2T.Models.RoleViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Role";
    Layout = null;
}

<div class="modalForm ">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateRole", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "ajaxForm", data_target = ".modalForm" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-fw"></i> New Role</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <span class="spinner pull-left"></span>
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" />
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

The Roles is the body class and I am sure that when I click the modal the jquery codes were triggered. For some reason, it does display the data and the modal but the UI is not working. This is how it looks like.
[image]

I have inspect element also and this is the result, 'modal-dialog' and 'modal-content' class were not included.
[image]

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u provide a jsfiddle for this issue?

Comment: Your form needs to be included in the modal-content and not wrap the modal-content. Can you include the JS code you have written to include the form in the modal?

Comment: @cdoshi added the codes

Answer (score 0):

Follow the hierarchy of div's to construct modals as recommended by bootstrap so that the styles are applied correctly. Currently, you have modalForm that encloses modal-content. Move your custom code inside modal-body for the styles to be applied correctly. In the snippet below, insert your custom code inside the modal-body div.

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="C2T Modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                 <!-- INSERT CUSTOM CODE HERE -->
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Comment: I have already a class modal-body inside the modalForm class div

Comment: the problem was why when I inspect element, the modal-content and modal-dialog div class not included

Comment: I do not see modal-content and modal-dialog in your code. Also, you cannot have modal-body inside your custom class modalForm. Its the opposite. Have modalForm inside modal-body